# Duplicating Multi-Fields in Saving Webform

Tags: custom-fields, webform-civicrm

I'm having an issue with D7's Webform CiviCRM Integration 5.8 duplicating entries in Civi. This wasn't an issue in 7.x-5.3 which is why I postpone upgrading to 5.8. Basically, I have a Drupal Webform with a few custom field sets that allow multiple records. In Civi's side, the custom field set includes multiple records shown in tab in a table (such as Name, Phone, Email).

A user goes to the webform and completes this information on the webform, for example:

Name        Phone  Email

- John Doe    XXXX  XXX@XXX.com
- Jane Doe    XXXX  XXX@XXX.com

A supervisor reviews the form and there's additional fields to open a case. Anytime a user saves the form, these two records duplicate from 2 rows to 4 rows (and so on). All fields are in the "Create/Edit" mode so it technically shouldn't create new entries.

Comment: Have you tested disabling CIviRules and seeing if the duplication still happens? Just in case you have a CiviRule in the mix

Comment: Duplication still happens with the CiviRule extension disabled (but it did resolve an error with CiviRule).